# Why this piece of code gives segmentation fault?

Tags: segmentation-fault, shared-memory

I'm working with named semaphores and shared memory can any one tell me why this piece of code gives segmentation fault?
this is a piece of code which is trying to implement the writer code for 
reader and writer problem using named semaphores and shared memory I need to know why this piece of code gives segmentation fault?

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 20                                                     
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    int fd;
    sem_t *db;
    int writtenData=0;
    int *addr=NULL; 
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    printf("hi\n");
    fd = shm_open("/mymem",O_CREAT|O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR); //segmentation fault here
    printf("by\n");
    ftruncate(fd,sizeof(int));
    if(fd==-1)
        printf("inja\n");
    db = sem_open("db",O_CREAT,0,1);
    addr = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    *(addr)= 0;


    //write db toshared memory
    //*
    //*

    while (writtenData<=MAX)
    {
        sem_wait(db);
        printf("The Writter acquires the clock\n");
        writtenData= *(addr);
        printf("The writer %d writes the value %d\n",pid,writtenData);
        writtenData++;
        *(addr)= writtenData;
        printf("The Writter release the Lock \n");
        sem_post(db);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program only crashes on second (and subsequent) invocation, and it doesn't crash where you think it does.

This:

```
db = sem_open("db",O_CREAT,0,1);
```

creates a named semaphore with *permissions* of 000 (i.e. no access for anybody). If that semaphore doesn't exist (first run) this call succeeds. If it does exist (second and subsequent runs), this call fails with `Permission denied`, and your attempt to use the result here:

```
sem_wait(db);
```

crashes with segmentation fault.

Lessons:

1. Learn to use debugger to know (rather than incorrectly guess) *where* your code is crashing.
2. *Always* check system functions for errors.
3. Read `man` pages carefully and make sure the arguments you supply make sense.